# Navbar does not collapse at the correct breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

On a site that am working on I have changed the breakpoint with one pixel. When you open [this page](http://www.uitjesinarnhem.nl/) in a 768 pixel wide window, the topmenu does not disappear and the menu button that should appear is not there.

When changed to a width of 767 pixels all is working fine.

I can't figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: Code? JSFiddle? How are we supposed to answer , do you want predictions?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Did you change something? Otherwise everything looks fine.

Comment: Can you reduce this problem to code that you can post to Stackoverflow? if the site you referenced changes or goes down, the question will no longer be clear to people who look at this post in the future.

Comment: It's just that in 768 width window the top menu is still there and I would like to have it collapsed just as it does in a smaller window.

Comment: @uber5001, Rob,  **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).

Comment: @KyleMit  Thanks for the link. I did not realise this. But since I have no idea where the problem is, I was under the impression a link should be enough instead of posting all code related to the website

Comment: @Rob, The idea is to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's not a trivial amount of work, but it helps you come up with a better idea of what's happening, other people trying to answer your question, and future visitors who are looking to learn from this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the `@grid-float-breakpoint` and the [recompiling](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

From the [navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar):

> #### Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px` (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

---

Or, if you don't want to re-compile, take [Skelly's code](https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w):

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

#### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/n97s3/)

Comment: I wanted to change that specific breakpoint to 768 and less instead of 767 and less. I fixed all except for the menu on top of the page. In 767px window the menu button does not appear and the Original menu is still there. And that is what I would like to change

Comment: Thanks KyleMit. I have not used Less but I will look into this. I'll get back to this later (during daytime probably ;) )